# Mean value theorem for the second derivative: $f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h) = h^2f''(\xi)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> State, without proof, the Mean Value Theorem for a function $$g:[z-\alpha,z+\alpha]\to\mathbb{R}$$ where $z$ is a real number and $\alpha$ is positive.
>
> Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is twice differentiable and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Prove that for all $h\gt0$ there exists $\xi\in(a-h,a+h)$ with $$f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)=h^2f''(\xi).$$
>
> Hint: consider the function $\varphi$ given by $$\varphi(t)=f(a+t)-2f(a)+f(a-t)-\left(\dfrac th\right)^2\big(f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-h)\big)$$

Attempt;
**First Part**
Here I just have to stat the definition of Mean Value Theorem;
If $g$ is continuous on $[z-a,z+a]$ and differentiable on $(z-a,z+a)$ the there exists $\xi \in (z-a,z+a)$ such that $$g'(\xi)=\dfrac{g(z+a)-g(z-a)}{(z+a) - (z-a)}= \dfrac{g(z+a)-g(z-a)}{2 a}$$

**Second Part** 
Now I am having trouble relating the Mean Value theorem to the equation provided in the hint;
$$\rho = f(a +t)-2f(a)+f(a-t)-(\dfrac{t}{h})^2(f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-t))$$
So from here how should I proceed? should I differentiate $\rho (t)$?

Any hints would be great,

Comment: You might want to apply the MVT to $\phi$ on the interval $(-h, h)$.

Comment: But $\phi (h) = \phi (-h) = 0$ ?

Comment: That's true, but so what? Perhaps you're thinking of the *intermediate* value theorem. The *mean* value theorem, which you just wrote down, says that there's a point where $\phi'(\xi) = $ the right hand side. In your case, this happens to be zero. Write down what it means for $\phi'(\xi)$ to be zero, and you'll be done, I believe.

Comment: But how would I get the $f''(\xi)$?

Answer (score 2):

The discussion of second part began in the comments:

- You might want to apply the MVT to $\phi$ on the interval $(-h, h)$. -- [John](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788992/suppose-f-is-twice-differentiable-prove#comment1634249_788992)
- But how would I get the $f''(\xi)$? -- [user148713](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788992/suppose-f-is-twice-differentiable-prove#comment1636175_788992)

To get the second derivative, apply  the mean value theorem *twice*. Since $\phi(-h)=\phi(0)=\phi(h)$, the derivative $\phi'$ has  two distinct zeros on $(-h,h)$. Therefore (by MVT, or simply Rolle's theorem) $\phi''$ has a zero on $(-h,h)$. Let's spell out what this means: there is $\tau$ such that

$$f''(a-\tau)+ f''(a+\tau)-\frac{2}{h^2} (f(a+h)-2f(a)+f(a-t))  = 0$$

Still not done -- we need just one $\xi$, not $a\pm \tau$. But since derivatives have the intermediate value property,  $f''$ attains the value $\frac12 (f''(a-\tau)+ f''(a+\tau))$  somewhere between $a\pm \tau$, and that's where $\xi$ is.

Comment: Using the Darboux property of derivatives looks like an overkill; I may be missing a simpler approach.