# If $f''(a)$ exists, then $f''(a) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ f(a+ h) - 2f(a) + f(a-h) }{h^2}$ without using Darboux Property

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

In the book of *The elements of Real Analysis* by Bartle, at page 220, it is asked that

> If $f''(a)$ exists, then $$f''(a) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ f(a+ h) -
>  2f(a) + f(a-h)  }{h^2}$$

I have proved a similar result for the first derivative of $f$, but I'm not able to show this result for the second derivative of $f$.

I have seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788992/mean-value-theorem-for-the-second-derivative-fah-2fafa-h-h2f-xi) this question, and it gives a proof for this question, but what I'm asking is that how can we prove this result without exploiting the Darboux property, and using the given hint in that question, and without using Taylor's theorem.

**Edit:**

Note that I want to see how can this result be obtained only using algebraic manipulations.

Comment: You can get the answer easily by applying L'Hospital's Rule just once. Are you allowed to use that infamous rule?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I would rather not to use it. I mean I don't want to use shortcuts, and want to see how can we handle it by algebraic manipulations.

Comment: You can't do this by algebraic manipulation. You must use L'Hospital's Rule or Taylor series or mean value theorem which is used to prove L'Hospital's Rule or Taylor. Also the question you have linked does not help in anyway to solve this question.

Comment: And L'Hospital's Rule is not a shortcut, it is precisely developed to solve such difficult problems. Often people use the rule blindly on any and every trivial limit problem and that has made it infamous.

Comment: Then how can we solve it by L'hospital rule ?

Comment: That's trivial just apply L'Hospital's to get the fraction as $$\frac{f'(a+h) - f'(a-h)} {2h}$$ and split the numerator by adding and subtracting $f'(a) $. You should get the limit as $f''(a) $. Note that you can apply L'Hospital's Rule only once here.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I know this is an old question, but I'm confused as to what you mean by "split the numerator"...

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Also, why can L'Hopital's only be used once here?

Comment: @c87: split the numerator $f'(a+h) - f'(a-h) $ as $(f'(a+h) - f'(a)) +(f'(a) - f'(a-h)) $. L'Hospital's Rule can be applied only once because if we apply it two times we get things like $f''(a+h) $ and we don't know if these exist. We only know the existence of $f''(a) $.