# If $f''$ exists on an interval centered at $x=a$, then $\lim \limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - 2f(a) +f(a-h)}{h^2} = f''(a)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, taylor-expansion, proof-explanation

If $f''$ exists on an interval centered at $x=a$, then $$\lim \limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h) - 2f(a) +f(a-h)}{h^2} = f''(a)$$

I've seen a few answers involving Taylor's theorem, and a few that were given hints for L'Hopital's. I do have a question though. If we use L'Hopital's rule, then the first derivative gives us the following :

$$ \frac{f'(a+h) - f'(a-h)}{2h}$$

What I don't understand is why people are saying we can only apply L'Hopital's once here, and say instead to "split the numerator with $f'$". What does this mean, to split the numerator? Why can L'Hopital's be used only once?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please rephrase your last question.?

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis There is a post ( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575513/if-fa-exists-then-fa-lim-h-to-0-frac-fa-h-2fa-fa-h ) from a few months ago, that says once you get to the first derivative, you cannot use L'Hopital's again. Instead, the user stated "split the numerator by adding and subtracting $f'(a)$, and we should get $f''(a)$".

Comment: @c87 in the cited question $f''$ exists only at $a$. If it exists on $(a-\epsilon) \cup (a+\epsilon)$ you can apply l'Hospital twice.

Comment: @user251257 So for my question where $f''$ exists on an interval centered at $x=a$, I'm fine applying twice?

Comment: @c87 you also need $f''(x) \to f''(a)$ for $x\to a$, which is a unnecessarily strong assumption

Comment: I have already clarified your doubts about split and usage of L'Hospital's Rule in my comments (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575513/if-fa-exists-then-fa-lim-h-to-0-frac-fa-h-2fa-fa-h#comment5675538_2575513). But it appears you are not convinced by the response.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I asked this question before I got a response from you

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{f'(a+h) - f'(a-h)}{2h}= \dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{f'(a+h)-f'(a)}{h}+\dfrac{f'(a+(-h)) - f'(a)}{-h}\right)\to \dfrac{1}{2}\left(f''(a)+f''(a)\right)=f''(a)$ when $h \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful for splitting the numerator. I see how we end up with $=f'(a)$, but do I need another step to show $=f''(a)$?

Comment: Yes. You are right about it. That's how you split the numerator into two terms.